# What is a letter of teaching philosophy?

Tags: faculty-application, teaching-statement

I am currently looking for jobs (lecturer in Mathematics) and I have been asked to include a "letter of teaching philosophy". Could any of you please explain what this is or point me to a reference? I couldn't find much after a Google search.

What should I include? I understand what my teaching philosophy is. For example, this includes:

- Preparing slides.
- Going from General to Particular.
- Presenting examples.
- Encouraging students to participate (e.g. by saying "well done!").
- Pointing out additional references.

Are this sort of things what I am supposed to include in the letter?

Comment: The list entry "going from general to particular" reads more like an didactic concept than a teaching philosophy for me.

Comment: You might want to read the [teaching-statement tag wiki](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/teaching-statement/info)

Comment: I believe the marked duplicate addresses your question. After reading that, if you still have a question, please [edit] this post to reflect what you have learned and what *specifically* you are unclear on.